# Why was Blofeld in a wheelchair in the beginning of For Your Eyes Only?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, for-your-eyes-only

In the pre title sequence of [*For Your Eyes Only*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082398/) Blofeld is in a wheelchair. Why?

Comment: There was in interesting answer to this in the recent BBC programming around the "Spectre" film. As stated by DVK, EON couldn't mention Blofeld by name due to the Kevin McClory lawsuit. However the character was made to resemble him and was killed by Bond to send the message that EON had little interest in the character (so little they happily killed him off), McClory had felt Blofeld was his Ace in hand in any negotiation and EON would settle to recover him.

Answer (score 15):

First of all, this is technically speaking an unnamed villain, NOT Blofeld (despite resembling him). To quote Wikipedia:

> John Hollis as the "bald villain in wheelchair",[12] voiced by Robert Rietti.[13] The character appears in the pre-credits sequence and is both unnamed and uncredited. The character contains a number of characteristics of Ernst Stavro Blofeld,[12] but could not be identified as such because of the legal reasons surrounding the Thunderball controversy with Kevin McClory claiming sole rights to the Blofeld character, a claim disputed by Eon

The reason the character is in the wheelchair is that in the last Bond movie where he was a character (Diamonds are Forever) Bond crashed a mini-sub that Blofeld was using to escape into a control center, blowing up the platform and presumably injuring Blofeld.

Answer (score 1):

You would have thought he was in the wheelchair because of what happend in O.H.M.S.S .
here is the scene [Bobsled chase neck injury](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fi0NingIKtA) blofelds neck gets caught in a branch severley injuring him . but he seems fine in diamonds are forever untill the end described in the answer above

Comment: In the end of OHMSS, Blofeld is **driving a car** in a neck brace, when the woman shoots Bond's wife. Hardly likely for a man in a wheelchair